# Dimension of a subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of operators on Hilbert space $H$ such that $\dim (\overline{\operatorname{Im} A_n})\leq \alpha$ where $\alpha\geq N_0$.

If $A_n\to A$ uniformly, then $AH=\lim A_n H$. Is it correct that $|\overline {AH}| \leq \lim |\overline{A_nH}|$ ?

My attempt:  Suppose $\{e^{(n)}_j\}_{j\in J_n}$ is an orthogonal basis for $\overline{A_n H}$. Clearly $\cup_n|\overline{A_n H}|\leq \alpha$. Also $\overline{AH} \subset \overline {span }\{e_j^{n};~~j\in J_n, n\in\Bbb N\}$,thus $\overline{ \textit{Im} ~A}\leq \alpha$.

Please check it. Thanks so much.

Comment: In what sense does $A_n \to A$? Uniform? Strong? Weak?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Uniformly